# How to produce a list of all words of a given Language from Wiktionary?

Tags: download, wiktionary

Say I want to produce a list of all Latin words from the **English** Wiktionary (because Wiktionary in English contains the most complete dictionary for Latin, and perhaps for every language).

More precisely, I want to produce a list of every entry that corresponds to a Latin word. These entries have one thing in common, namely, that the website address has the following type:

```
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/<word>#Latin
```

For instance, *[sensorum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensorum#Latin)*. The key here is that 1) the domain is the English wiktionary (en.wiktionary) and 2) the website ends in #Latin.

Based on other answers (e.g. [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18273/download-all-words-from-wiktionary-for-offline-use)), I found out there is a directory containing all pages of the English wiktionary [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/). But this does not, as far as I can see, separates by language. The "main" file (`nwiktionary-latest-all-titles.gz`) contains a list of around 7 million objects (words?). This might be the full list of pages in English. I want only those pertaining to a certain language.

There seems to be related posts [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92141/scraper-for-words-from-wiktionary) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770547/how-to-retrieve-wiktionary-word-content) but I cannot make sense of the answers for my own case. There is also [this resource](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/) to extract items from Wiktionary, but haven't figure out how to use it for my purposes yet (I used it for extracting lists of categories [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7642/how-to-search-for-nouns-ending-in-ile/7644#7644) but not all words in Wiktionary are indexed into categories).

Anyone can provide some hints on how to do it?

PS: if this is off-topic, please suggest where this might fit better.

Answer (score 2):

Working with the full Wiktionary dump is hard, so I recommend using data sources which extract the parts you are interested in and present them in an easier to digest format.

[wiktextract](https://github.com/tatuylonen/wiktextract) looks like a great fit for your request, especially [this list](https://kaikki.org/dictionary/Latin/nonsenses.html).

If you are willing to accept data from the Latin Wiktionary, [dbnary](http://kaiko.getalp.org/about-dbnary/) is also an excellent data source. If you prefer relational data to RDF triples, I provide [downloadable sqlite databases](https://www.wikdict.com/page/download) as part of [WikDict](https://www.wikdict.com/).